# TO-18 case connected to device?

Tags: transistors, packages

I'm seeing some weird behavior in a circuit I just soldered up.  I haven't done detailed debugging yet, but it occurred to me that the metal case on the 2N2222A transistors I used might be connected to one of the leads.  It seems that this is often true with some of the larger metal cans, (e.g. TO-3 and TO-220), but I couldn't find anything definitive about the TO-18 package.

Comment: Use a multi meters continuity test mode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first 2N2222A datasheet on Google, in the TO-18 mechanical data:

[image: TO-18 package bottom]

Note the lack of an isolation ring around pin 2 (collector).

Comment: Ah... I ended up measuring one just now and you're exactly right, but now I know how to read it off the datasheet too!